# how to open a new tab in bash console from bashrc in windows

Tags: bash, function, cmder

I have windows 8 on my laptop and I'm trying to create a bash function in `bashrc` that would allow me to open few files in sublime text and launch opera and chrome at the same time, I'd love to set my working environment up with a simple command from console.

However, when I tried to do it from a single tab, I found out that after launching the editor the tab is processing it and that's it, it doesnt open the browsers. So, I figured, I should probably create a new tab in console that would take care of opening the opera and chrome, but I dont know how to do that from bash.

I tried googling the problem for couple of hours, I saw a lot of info for users of linux but none for windows users.
Here is my bash function, maybe seeing it might help you guys:

```
alias sl="/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe" $* #(its my alias for sublime text)
alias browsers="opera & chrome" $* #(another one for opening the browsers)
run () {
    cd Users/Man/
    sl .bashrc tasks.txt
    cd Desktop/work/her*/
    sl Gulp*
    cd /less\ components/src/
    sl *
    cd ../../html\ components/
    sl *
    browsers
}
```

Or, guys, maybe there is some other way to set up the environment with only one command in console.

I'm using cmder for windows

Comment: I can't test myself at the moment, but have you tried `sl * &` to run as background process? ConEmu also has a `-new_console` command which might be helpful? http://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html

Comment: aliases don't use arguments the `$*` on that `sl` alias is being expanded immediately (to the empty string most likely) and disappearing. If you need arguments you use a shell function. And yes, `sl &` is likely what you need here.

Comment: Also, bash is bash. If you found info "for Linux users" then use it.

Comment: thanks a lot, guys, it really helped!